# insert data from a table to another table sorted by column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

There is a temp table `TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035` with fields:

```
ACTION_OBJID NUMBER,
CONTRACT_OBJID NUMBER,
STATUS varchar2(40),
UPDATE_DATE DATE
```

This contains 7 million data.i want to create seven different temp tables with data from TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035 sorted by action_objid and each containing  1 million records. **The column ACTION_OBJID is not a sequence .**

I tried using rownum but that inputs random  data.

For EG:

Temp1 : data containing action_objid from 5 ,8...to 1100000(as action_objid is not a sequence,this much is 1 million data).
Similarly, for other 6 temp tables.
I am using oracle 10g.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is this for performance reasons? Does ACTION_OBJID have any correlation with anything real or is it just a surrogate key? The specifics of the question make me think you are trying to do some kind opf partitioning for performance, and there are definitly better ways to do this.

Comment: using this temp table ,daily updation will be does on a table on prod...but becuase i am doing live load(ie prod application will be running along with the script,i am limiting updates to 1 million per day.can you suggest better way to do it?i am using action_objid to update the prod table(it is the pk of the prod table)

Comment: So you are trying to improve insert / update performance by partitioning the table. This is often achieved through partitioned tables with the advantange that it is transparent to the user (i.e. you don't to create and maintani different physical tables). Takl to your DBA or do some research online about Oracle partitioned tables

Comment: i agree.previously i was using range partition on the temp table itself,with range as 1 mil for each partition.however,as the action_objid is not in a sequnce and i wanted to fix the data till 1 mil in the partition(the partition range will be now decided dynamically,previously for eg for partition one 1-1000000,which may or may not contain 1 mil data) .i am using temp tables to incorporate the changes mentioned in the question as i am not able to form the queries using range partition on the same table.If you have any ideas/pointers to it,it will be helpful.

Comment: Why does it need to be exactly one million? Is it be because action_objid is not evenly distributed? From a performance perspective it shouldn't matter if one partition has 800,000 and the other has 1,200,000

Comment: yes,It is because action_objid is not evenly distributed.I understand that it doesnt matter if it contains 800k or 1200k...but because of impact on other system in production i have to limit it to 1 million..actually i am updating columns of an prod table using this temp table...because of some constraint in prod ,am doing this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE_1
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT *
            FROM TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035
            WHERE ACTION_OBJID > 0
            ORDER BY ACTION_OBJID)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000000
```

Then repeat the above for each of your other temp tables, replacing `WHERE ACTION_OBJID > 0` with `(SELECT MAX(ACTION_OBJID) FROM name of previous temp table)`.  So for TEMP_TABLE_2 the statement would be

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE_2
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT *
            FROM TMP_OA_PSTN_CMP_11035
            WHERE ACTION_OBJID > (SELECT MAX(ACTION_OBJID) FROM TEMP_TABLE_1)
            ORDER BY ACTION_OBJID)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 1000000
```

Share and enjoy.